# Why reading large csv file gives "blob:bef00fec-4660-4291-a3e2-4c5b96205970?type=Text"?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, browser

I'm facing issues reading large csv in the browser. When the file size is small for example 100KB, it is working and showing the actual data.

Consider the following code:

```
const csv = csv_upload_btn.files[0].data;

console.log(csv);
```

With a large file 20 MB, it shows "blob:bef00fec-4660-4291-a3e2-4c5b96205970?type=Text" in the console, but I expect the actual data. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Try a file reader

```js
const csvFile = csv_upload_btn.files[0];
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    const text = event.target.result;
    console.log(text);
});
reader.readAsText(csvFile);
```